# Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

Can you play Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare from a disc without needing a hard drive? What about on a USB stick or external harddrive?

Comment: If you have a USB stick that can store the 45GB install, I'm impressed.

Comment: @Studoku There are flash drives that can store upwards of 64GB.

Comment: @crayzeedude And I am impressed by them.

Comment: Hi user99239, what platform are you asking about?

Comment: As in, Xbox 360, PC, PS3, Xbox One or PS4?

Comment: As of early 2018, there are now USB sticks with capacities of 128GB, and they are tiny, high quality, and inexpensive (about 20-30 US dollars). AND - 256GB (!) varieties are also available, though the cost of these is around 5x that of the lower capacities.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a PC, it will work. If you have a completely functional PC that has everything else (RAM, grahpics card, motherboard) I guess you could in theory. You could store and download the game/Steam on a usb with ALOT of memory. However, this is impossible because if you have no hard drive you have no operating system...

Comment: by the way, i assume this is an entirely theoretical question because like i said I seriosuly doubt its possible (or at least by no convient means..

Comment: +1 Steam, at its largest (not counting anything in the `SteamApps` folder) is around 1GB, so as long as you have a 64GB USB stick.. It's possible. Though to say that the read/write speed is going to be horrible... So prepare for *REALLY* long loading times.